# Android - WindowManager

Tags: java, android

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vejam o layout acima com uma tela inicial padrão de um celular qualquer. Vejam que eu destaquei a tela padrão do celular com um texto (Shadow Effect) e duas notificações do android (view1 e view2).

Eu queria implementar isso em um RelativeLayout normal, com os aspectos: sombra, e duas views no estilo dessa printscreen.

É possível usando WindowManager? Ou WindowManager não serve para esse caso?

Se não servir, o que eu posso usar?

Comment: Você não necessariamente ira precisar interagir com o `WindowManager`. Minha dúvida é se você quer que o fundo do aplicativo/Activity seja transparente (ou com fundo em alpha) ou ter esse efeito de "modal" (seria o seu Shadow effect?) com um fundo qualquer? As sombras você pode emular com um Drawable ou usando a propriedade elevation (Android 5).

Comment: Oi, Wakim. Então, é exatamente isso que eu quero. É que eu vi uma API que utilizava isso e achei que eu poderia fazer algo parecido. No meu caso, eu teria 3 layouts.

Layout 1: Tela principal;
Layout 2: Após a tela principal ser carregada, o layout 2 será mostrado como se fosse apenas um efeito de sombra para o layout 3.

É como se eu "ajustasse" o brilho da tela (layout1) para algo mais escuro (com o layout2) e depois mostraria o layout 3 com um efeito de "focus" e com o "brilho total".

Espero que tenha entendido, abraços!

Comment: Então não precisa de fato aplicar sobra nas duas Views. Acho que da pra fazer de duas formas: PopupWindow (com fundo transparente e as duas Views) ou usando uma Activity com fundo transparente. Da uma olhada nessas três perguntas que podem ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221488/blur-or-dim-background-when-android-popupwindow-active e http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542517/activity-with-transparent-background e http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406060/android-how-to-blur-glass-frost-current-activity

Comment: Entendi! Muito obrigado pelas respostas. Abraço!